# Format Large Block of Text in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I have assigned a section of text to `Description`. This "Description" is pulled from a text file depending on the `id` of an item.

```
private string _description = string.Empty;

public string Description
{
    get { return this._description; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._description, value); }

}
```

This works fine and returns the description. But it is returned as a large block/wall of text.

I tried the following but it doesn't work well, it only formats the defined text and doesn't help me because `Description` is dynamic.

```
 String ITEM_CONTENT = String.Format(
     "Item Content: {0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}",
     "proin lobortis sollicitudin augue elit mus congue fermentum parturient fringilla euismod feugiat.");
```

I am fitting the description into a TextBlock on my XAML page

```
<TextBlock x:Name="decription" Text="{Binding Description}" 
       FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="Auto"  
       MaxWidth="1400" LineHeight="35" Padding="20"/>
```

How do I format this `Description` so that it is neater, with line breaks or new lines after every 5 sentences ending with a fullstop?

EDIT:

Tried this but still didn't work

```
private string _description = string.Empty;

public string Description
{
    get { return this._description; }

    set
    {
        var description = string.Empty;
        var substrings = "".Split( '.' );
        for ( int i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++ )
        {
            description += substrings[i];
            if ( i%5 == 0 )
            {
                description += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        this.SetProperty(ref this._description, description);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see edits above

Comment: what are you fitting it into?

Comment: @Noctis please see edits

Comment: OK, In that case you get wrapping, and you just want to add new lines, have a look at e.beyer answer, you can do something like that.

Comment: With your last edit of what you tried, you're doing the split on an empty string "". It should happen on `value`. So it would be `var substrings = value.Split( '.' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just parse the text, and insert the line break character after every 5 periods, and rebuild the string.

```
  private string _description = string.Empty;
  public string Description
  {
     get
     {
        return _description;
     }
     set
     {
        var description = string.Empty;
        var substrings = value.Split( new[] { '.', '?', '!' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
        for ( var i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++ )
        {
           description += substrings[i] + ".";
           if ( i % 5 == 0 && i != 0 )
           {
              description += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
           }
        }
        _description = description;
     }
  }
```

Comment: `       set 
            {
                var description = string.Empty;
                var substrings = "".Split( '.' );
                for ( int i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++ )
                {
                   description += substrings[i];
                   if ( i%5 == 0 )
                   {
                       description += Environment.NewLine;
                   }
                }
                this.SetProperty(ref this._description, description); 
            }` Tried this but didn't work. Text is the same way

Comment: make sure you do set the above `description` to your `Description` property, otherwise, you won't see the changes :)

Comment: @Tester - I've updated my answer. I had a silly mistake as I added before testing. I also added a better line for parsing end of sentences. Give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754036%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It should clear things up and give you some extra options.

Also, on your input, you should do `"\r\n"`, or better yet:

```
String ITEM_CONTENT = String.Format("Item Content: {0}{1}{0}{1}{0}{1}{0}{1}",
                    "proin lobortis sollicitudin augue elit mus congue
                        fermentum parturient,fringilla euismod feugiat.",
                    Environment.NewLine);
```

---

**Edit:**
Try this:

```
public string Description
{
    get { return _description; }

    set 
    {
        _description = string.Empty;

        var substrings = value.Split( '.' );
        for ( int i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++ )
        {
            _description += substrings[i];
            if ( i%5 == 0 )
            {
                _description += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }   
    }
}
private string _description = string.Empty;
```

not sure why you're trying to set with a ref and do all that. Simply edit your private string (`_description`), and that should do it.

Comment: But `ITEM_CONETENT` would not be the text in the example, it would be getting the descriptions from a data file